# Multiple email input in Angular 7

Tags: angular7

I want to create a multiple email input, below I attached an image, Please instruct me for a build that email input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBVhk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically multiple tags selection and there are many 3rd party solutions available to implement them, you can use [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos) to get the same results that you want,

**ngTagsInput Demo:**

[image: ngTagsInput Demo]